# jQuery Plugin Stored Values

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, closures

I'm working on a jquery plug in and I'm running into a problem saving properties for later use.  In the example below, the console output is `18, 50, 50` when I'm looking for `18, 50, 18`.  I understand why this is happening, but I can't figure out a good way to save `properties` for use in multiple different methods.  I have a feeling I'm missing something very obvious, but I'm just not seeing it.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello</h1>
        <h2>World</h2>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            (function ($) {
                var commonOperations, methods, properties;

                commonOperations = function () {
                    console.log(properties.height);
                };

                methods = {
                    init : function (overrides) {
                        var defaults;
                        defaults = { height: 18 };
                        properties = $.extend(defaults, overrides);

                        commonOperations();
                    },

                    foo : function () {
                        commonOperations();
                    }
                };

                $.fn.myPlugin = function (method) {
                    if (methods[method]) {
                        return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
                    } else if (typeof method === 'object' || !method) {
                        return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
                    } else {
                        $.error('Method ' + method + ' does not exist for jQuery.myPlugin');
                    }
                };
            }(jQuery));

            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("h1").myPlugin();
                $("h2").myPlugin({ height: 50 });
                $("h1").myPlugin("foo");
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the nature of your plugin, but it's likely that using `.data()` to store the properties on a per-element basis would make sense.

```
   init: function(overrides) {
     return this.each(function() {
       var defaults = { whatever: "foo" };
       $(this).data('properties', $.extend(defaults, overrides));
     });
   }
```

Then the other methods always pull the "properties" object from the element:

```
    foo : function () {
      return this.each(function() {
        commonOperations.call(this, $(this).data('properties'));
      });
    }
```

Comment: +1 - supporting information can be found here: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring#Data

Comment: Thanks. That makes perfect sense.